# How to evaluate php code in a content type text field in Drupal 6

Tags: nodes, 6

I have a content type with some fields. Normally I would user "filtered HTML" option as input format, but now I want to user "PHP filter". I've placed my php code into the field

```
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

But all I get is this:

```
<p id="footer-text-left"><!--?php echo "test"; ?--></p>
```

"PHP Evaluator" is enabled and it's the only filter applied to that input format.
Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have a WYSIWYG editor enabled by any chance? CKEditor or similar would wrap the output in paragraph tags like that.

Comment: Nope, maybe my installation is broken. I think this should work as it is.

Comment: Are you sure you are realy using the PHP filter in this particular node field?

Comment: Same issue here. I have checked admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT-TYPE/fields, clicked "manage fields" and made sure PHP was enabled on the field.